# Scraping <li> contents with PHP dom

Tags: php, html, dom

how I could use PHP dom screen scraping to pull the contents of an HTML tag called

`<li style="margin-top:10px">`

positioned in one of my pages?

I want to get all the contents of the `<li>` tag and display it as html code.

Comment: I find using preg_match to be sufficient for scraping. Also the html doesn't have to be welformed xml.

Comment: @Gerben: Please.. never suggest using regexs for html parsing again :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: LOL the Regex Enforcement Agency arrived in only a minute this time.

Comment: @ThiefMaster He doesn't want to parse the html, just extract a certain part of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use simpleXML and xpath. Supposing your HTML is all stored in the string `$html`, this may fit your need:

```
// Load your html from a file
$html = $file_get_contents("/path/to/page.html");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($html);

$li = $xml->xpath("//li[@style='margin-top:10px]");
echo $li->asXML();
```

Comment: @Callum Whyte See addition above : `file_get_contents()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$html='<li style="margin-top:10px">hello <b>World</b></li>';
if( preg_match('|<li style="margin-top:10px">(.*?)</li>|', $html, $matches) )
{
  $licontent = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: This will actually do the job at hand.  Just don't get into the habit of using regex for more complicated parsing.